# I'm struggling to get a foreach loop working to loop through each element of a LinkedList

Tags: c#, foreach, linked-list, iteration, depth-first-search

Im trying to do a Depth first traversal on graph node but I cant get my for each loop to loop correctly

Here is the code for doing the search
The foreach line is the problem

```
public void DepthFirstTraverse(T startID, ref List<T> visited)
        {
            LinkedList<T> adj;
            Stack<T> toVisit = new Stack<T>();
            GraphNode<T> current = new GraphNode<T>(startID);

            toVisit.Push(startID);

            while (toVisit.Count != 0)
            {
                current.ID = toVisit.Peek();
                toVisit.Pop();
                visited.Add(current.ID);
                Console.WriteLine(current.GetAdjList());
                foreach(T n in current.GetAdjList()) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Loop working");
                    if(toVisit.Contains(n)==false && visited.Contains(n)==true)
                    {
                        toVisit.Push(n);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Here is the graphnode code, it calls the getadjlist and should loop through for each element in that list, currently it doesnt loop at all
     public class GraphNode
    {
        private T id; // data stored in the node (“id” of the  node).
        private LinkedList adjList; // adjacent list of the node

```
    // constructor 
    public GraphNode(T id)
    {
        this.id = id;
        adjList = new LinkedList<T>();
    }

    // set and get the data stored in the node 
    public T ID
    {
        set { id = value; }
        get { return id; }     
    }


    //add a directed edge from “this” node to the node "to”
    public void AddEdge(GraphNode<T> to)
    {
        adjList.AddFirst(to.ID);
    }

    // returns the adjacent list of the node
    public LinkedList<T> GetAdjList()
    {
        return adjList;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean for ( n : current.GetAdjList() ) .. this is for each syntax in Java

Comment: Why are you creating in 3rd line new instance of GraphNode ???
How you want to traverse/iterate its edges? It doesn't have any, it's a new object!

Comment: I do not write in C# but this looks suspicious to me `visited.Contains(n)==true`. Why do you expect to `visited.Contains(n)` to be true before adding `n` to `visited` ?